# leaflet map doesnt load on tablet and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, leaflet

I have a problem with leaflet's rendering on screens smaler than desktop,
can anyone help me sort this out, here is how im trying to build and use my map

```
var cities = L.layerGroup(locationArray);
            var mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=blablahblah';
            var grayscale = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.light'}),
                streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets'});
            if(map) {
                map.remove();
            }
            map = L.map('searchMap', {
                center: [
                    35.7011398,
                    51.3892971
                ],
                zoom: 5,
                layers: [streets, cities]
            });
            var baseLayers = {
                "Grayscale": grayscale,
                "Streets": streets
            };
            var overlays = {
                "Cities": cities
            };
            L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
            //Check Location exist

            if(locationArrayBound.length) {
                //Fit Bounds
                map.fitBounds(locationArrayBound).setMaxZoom(15);

            }
```

Comment: BTW a tablet is considered a mobile device.

Comment: How is `searchMap` defined in HTML and CSS?

Comment: ghybs, thanks for your comments but thats not the point of this post

Comment: peebee that's just an id and its used like this
<div id="searchMap" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; direction: ltr">